# Passing a string in onclick function's attribute of element dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass a string in the onClick event handler function's arguments of the dynamically created anchor element, see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shmdhussain/bXYe4/.

I am not able to pass the string to the function, but i am able to pass the number integer to the function. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

html:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" class="cssfx"/>

        <script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="colon.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="mytest">

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var elem=[  {"name":"husain","url":"http://google.com","age":21},
            {"name":"ismail","url":"http://yahoo.com","age":22},
            {"name":"nambi","url":"http://msn.com","age":23}
         ]

jQuery(function($){
    var str="";
    for(i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
        str+="<a href='#' onclick='test('"+elem[i].url+"')'>dd</a><br><br>"
        console.log(str);

    }
    $('.mytest').html(str);

});

function test(url){
    console.log("url is "+url);
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to use proper string sytax. This

```
"<a href='#' onclick='test('"+elem[i].url+"')'>dd</a><br><br>"
```

will result in

```
<a href='#' onclick='test('http://domain.tld')'>dd</a><br><br>
```

You cannot use ' for onclick and the parameters of test. Use \" instead.

```
"<a href='#' onclick='test(\""+elem[i].url+"\")'>dd</a><br><br>"
```

Which results in

```
<a href='#' onclick='test("http://domain.tld")'>dd</a><br><br>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is, that `str+="<a href='#' onclick='test('"+elem[i].url+"')'>dd</a><br/><br/>";` will return a string like `"<a href='#' onclick='test('your_url')'>dd</a><br/><br/>"`. This will generate a html like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='test('your_url')'>dd</a><br/><br/>
```

In this case, the onclick attribute contains only 'test('.

Try this:

```
str+="<a href='#' onclick='test(\""+elem[i].url+"\")'>dd</a><br/><br/>";
```

This will generate a html like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='test("your_url")'>dd</a><br/><br/>
```

Comment: @Sébastien, str+="<a href='#' onclick='test(\""+elem[i]+"\")'>dd</a><br/><br/>"; How should we pass object to test function directly as you pass onclick='test(\""+elem[i].url+"\")'>.....in this scenario.You have passed url here but how can we pass object arr[i] . Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

Directly use:

```
test('"+elem[i].url+"')
```

instead of:

```
'test('"+elem[i].url+"')'
```

to pass the string inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, here is your answer;

```
var elem=[  {"name":"husain","url":"http://google.com","age":21},
    {"name":"ismail","url":"http://yahoo.com","age":22},
    {"name":"nambi","url":"http://msn.com","age":23}
]

jQuery(function($){
    var str="";
    for(i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
        var a =$('<a>',{href:'#',text:'dd'});
        a.click(function(e){
               test(elem[i].url)
        });
        $('.mytest').append(a).append($('</br>')).append($('</br>'));

    }
});

function test(url){
    console.log("url is "+url);
}
```

Comment: This is also another method to implement, thanks Whispered. But i implement in the same way as i want from AmShaegar 's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For passing multiple parameters you can cast the string by concatenating it with the ASCII value like, for single quotes we can use `&#39;`

```
var str= "&#39;"+ str+ "&#39;";
```

the same parameter you can pass to the `onclick(str)` event.It is helpful in  cases where we pass multiple parameters.It works with every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Directly use:

```
test('elem[i].url')
```

instead of:

```
test('"+elem[i].url+"')
```

to pass the string inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var funcName = "SelectPickerBtnSelectEvent('" + str + "')";
$(".btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-light").attr("onclick", funcName);
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps instead, use a data attribute on the element to hold the string.
then in the function retrieve the data.