# Passing array value as javascript onclick function parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the code below i'm trying to run a function screw(); giving it the value of the span as a parameter to use

```
socket.on('usernames', function(data) {
  var html ='';
  for(i=0; i< data.length; i++){
    html += '<a><span onclick ="screw(data[i]);" style="font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer;">' + data[i] + '</span></a><br/>'
  }
  $('#online').html(html);
});
```

Please note that the "data" parameter being passed into the above function is an array automatically generated on the server side

here is the "screw" function in action. Im trying to at least alert the value it gets

```
  function screw(vem){
alert(vem);
```

}

But i keep getting that a reference error that data is undefined. Please can you spot what i'm doing wrong?'

Comment: Another one — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035617/passing-a-string-in-onclick-functions-attribute-of-element-dynamically-created

Comment: can you show us how `data` looks like please?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos data is an array being updated when a user logs into the page with a username. All this is done on the server-side with the following code


`code`
var users = {};
socket.on('new-user', function(data, callback){
   if (data in users){
    callback(false);
   }else{
    callback(true);
    socket.usernames = data;
    users[socket.usernames] = socket.id;
    update();
   }
  });
function update(){
   io.emit('usernames', Object.keys(users));
  } 
`code`

Comment: @Rayon Thanks, i've seen my error. It was actually wrong string the syntax. in the onclick line
Here's the right one :
`code`    
    html += "<a><span onclick ='screw(\""+data[i]+"\");' style='font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer;'>" + data[i] + "</span></a><br/>"
    
`code`